# matlab, how to plot the "root locus"

Tags: matlab, for-loop, root

Given a function (call it sys(s)), we can use matlab: `rlocus(sys)`  to plot the root locus of that function.

However,if we are given a function with a parameter (say b), eg sys(s)=(2s+2+**b**)/s , how can I use matlab to plot the rlocus(sys) as a function of the parameter b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `b` changes between 1 and 100 with intervals of 1.

```
b = 1:100;
```

We need to create axes and hold them, so that we can plot root loci on top of each other.

```
axes();
hold('on');
```

Now we need to create a transfer function for each `b` and plot its root locus.

```
for idx = 1:length(b)
   sys = tf([2 2+b(idx)], [1 0]);
   rlocus(sys);
end
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image: Root locus]

I could not find a vectorized solution, so it takes quite a long time. This took 45 seconds on my computer. If you need to calculate many values, you will need a vectorized solution.

---

To add a legend, you need to create a cell array to store `b` values.

```
legendStr = cell(1, length(b));
```

Then, inside the for loop you need to convert `b` values to string and store them in `legendStr`.

```
legendStr{idx} = num2str(b(idx));
```

After the for loop add the legend to the plot.

```
legend(legendStr)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I am also wondering, how can I indicate on the graph that, which color is corresponding to which b value?

Comment: @user3222184 I added information about adding a legend. Hope it helps.